# passing command line arguments to selenium python test case

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium python automation test where i want to pass url of website as a parameter to function. I will be calling the function via command line.

my_python_code.py

```
class my_automation_class(unittest.TestCase)
    
    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("url_link", help="display url")
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

    def test_my_automation(self):
        
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()

        driver.get(self.args.url_link)
        //performs some operation after this

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main(testRunner=HTMLTestRunner(output='Reports'),exit=False)
```

When I ran this via command line

> python my_python_code.py "https://www.netflix.com/in/ "

I am getting

> ERROR [0.000000s]: unittest.loader._FailedTest.https://www

> AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute 'https://www'

I am not sure why it's not working. Is there any other way i can pass arguments to selenium python  test case ?

Comment: The parsing statements should be under the if __name__ == '__main__': statement or in the set-up function.

Comment: @DevangSanghani Thank you for your answer, i added it in the setup func, but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the code here?

Comment: @DevangSanghani hey , I have updated the code

Comment: You should run it like this : 

`python my_python_code.py  --url_link="https://www.netflix.com/in/ "`

Comment: @DevangSanghani  yes , i was executing " python my_python_code.py "https://www.netflix.com/in/ "  , and i just tried your way but unfortunetly it did not work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DevangSanghani do i have to write anything in  if name == 'main':

Comment: @DevangSanghani  module '__main__' has no attribute 'url_link' ,  AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '=' and  AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'https://www'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241776/discussion-between-devang-sanghani-and-geek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class my_automation_class(unittest.TestCase)               
      def setUp(self):
          chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
          chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
          chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
          self.url_link = args.url_link
            
      def test_my_automation(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.maximize_window()
          driver.get(self.url_link)
          //performs some operation after this
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument("url_link", help="display url")
     args = parser.parse_args()
     sys.argv.pop()            
     unittest.main(testRunner=HTMLTestRunner(output='Reports'),exit=False)
```

Run code:

```
    python my_python_code  --url_link="https://www.netflix.com/in/"
```

Comment: I have one more doubt , i want to run this using pytest and create a report of it in html, how does this work ?  i tried "pytest -v -s --json-report --json-report-indent=4 --json-report-file=report/report.json --html=report/report.html conftest.py"

Comment: Pls try it and post  a new question in case you need help.